# How to read a parquet file in Azure Databricks?

Tags: python, parquet, azure-databricks

I have few parquet files stored in my storage account, which I am trying to read using the below code. However it fails with error as incorrect syntax. Can someone suggest to me as whats the correct way to read parquet files using azure databricks?

```
val data = spark.read.parquet("abfss://containername@storagename.dfs.core.windows.net/TestFolder/XYZ/part-00000-1cf0cf7b-6c9f-41-a268-be-c000.snappy.parquet")
display(data)
```

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: hi @ZZZSharePoint, can you please share the error image, and also please confirm the above files are in delta format or not ?

Answer (score 1):

> abfss://containername@storagename.dfs.core.windows.net/TestFolder/XYZ/part-00000-1cf0cf7b-6c9f-41-a268-be-c000.snappy.parquet

As per the above abfss URL  you can use delta or parquet format in the storage account.

**Note:** If you created delta table, part file creates automatically like this `part-00000-1cf0cf7b-6c9f-41-a268-be-c000.snappy.parquet`.As per above code it is not possible to read parquet file in delta format .

I have written the datafram `df1` and overwrite into a storage account with parquet format.

```
df1.coalesce(1).write.format('parquet').mode("overwrite").save("abfss://<container>@<stoarge_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder>/<sub_folder>")
```

> **Scala**

```
val df11 = spark.read.format("parquet").load("abfss://<container>@<stoarge_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/demo/d121/part-00000-tid-2397072542034942773-def47888-c000.snappy.parquet")
display(df11)
```

> **python**

```
df11 = spark.read.format("parquet").load("abfss://<container>@<stoarge_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/demo/d121/part-00000-tid-2397072542034942773-def47888-c000.snappy.parquet")
display(df11)
```

**Output:**

[image]